# What does 'value' represent in domain definitions?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

From the [ORM API Docs](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/orm.html#domains):

```
value:
variable type, must be comparable (through operator) to the named field
```

Either the documentation is vague or I'm particularly dense today. What does this *mean*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`field_name` is the actual field of record which be compared to filter the records, `value` is the entity with which the records `field_name` will be compared with. Let's say `domain=[('partner_id','=','1')]`, will check the field `partner_id` to be equal to `1` and filter the model records accordingly.

Comment: Can i use this to reference another field? like assume i want to compare a field with the current choice in a selection field

Comment: Yes you can use reference to another field, but that field must be present in the view.

Comment: I would set the value to the field name in that case? and it would reference said field's type?

Comment: Yes whatever value of the given field in the view will be compared with records field.